# Sum of squares proof where $N=n_{UC}+n_{TX}$

Tags: self-study, proof, sums-of-squares

$TX$ is variable that indicates treatment status ($TX=1$ if the patient gets the new treatment, and $0$ otherwise, and $UC = 1 - TX$ indicates they got the standard treatment).

Of $N$ patients, $n_{UC}$ get usual care and $n_{TX}$ get new treatment.

If $n_{UC} + n_{TX} = N$, show that $\sum_i(TX_i-\overline{TX} )(TX_i-\overline{TX}) = n_{UC}\cdot n_{TX}/N$.

Comment: Is this an equivalent phrasing? "If $nUC + nTX = N$, show that: $\sum(TX_i-\bar{TX})^2 = nUC\times nTX \div N$"

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing. (a) What's UC and TX? (and if it doesn't matter what they are, why not use a simpler notation?) (b) Are these values counts or something? (c) Is this for some subject?

Comment: Nick: the notation you used is correct.

Comment: No prob; your $\LaTeX$-fu is stronger, thus I am learning. :)

Comment: TX is an indicator variable.  Of N patients, nUC get usual care and nTX get new treatment.

Comment: Please check my new edits are correct.

Comment: They are. Thanks for your help in posting the question correctly!

Comment: Can you address part (c) in my comment above? More specifically, this looks like a standard textbook question, and as such it probably should have the `self-study` tag. We treat those question [differently](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), providing hints in return for a clear explanation of what you've already tried and where you got stuck. If this is for some subject, or even just an exercise for personal study, you should add the tag.

Comment: Another way of expressing the opening statement is: Tx indicates treatment status.  For patients receiving new treatment TX = 1, for patients receiving usual care, TX = 0.

Comment: This is a question from a health economics course.  I will add the self-study tag.  Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: How far did you get? Did you try expanding the square in the sum and simplifying that? i.e. did you trying taking $$(TX_i-\overline{TX} )(TX_i-\overline{TX})=$$ and expanding the product out?

Comment: I comfortable with showing the proof for expanding this so that it is equal to sum(Tx)^2 - (sumTx)^2/N.  I am stuck on the nuc*ntx/N relationship.

Comment: Don't jump so far ahead, that's probably why you're lost. So you can do this much: $\sum_i(TX_i-\overline{TX} )(TX_i-\overline{TX})=\sum_i TX_i^2-2\overline{TX}\sum_i TX_i +N\,\overline{TX}^2 =\sum_i TX_i^2-N\,\overline{TX}^2$? Then what's $TX_i^2$ (remember, it's always 0 or 1 - what happens in each case)? After that, what's $N\,\overline{TX}^2$? Once you simplify both terms, you can make progress

Comment: As a follow-up, I wanted to let you know that I finished solving the problem.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am glad you got it sorted out. I didn't see your comment when you posted it because you didn't @name me (which notifies me). I'll post a complete answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use a more concise notation (my $T$ is your $TX$) but you can convert it.

Let $p$ be the proportion of the patients with $T=1$ for a binary variable $T$, i.e. let $p = T/N$. Then:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_i(T_i-\overline{T} )(T_i-\overline{T})&=&\sum_i T_i^2-2\overline{T}\sum_i T_i +N\,\overline{T}^2 \\
&=&\sum_i T_i^2-N\,\overline{T}^2 \\
&=&Np - Np^2 \\
&=& Np\cdot(1-p) \\
&=& n_T \cdot (N-n_T)/N
\end{eqnarray}

After converting back to your notation (and a minor triviality), that's the required result.